# how to implement a like button for carousels in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a "carousel" displaying fruits,
also has a like button beside the carousel,

im loading carousel items with fruits (arr of objects) which is a response of a GET req,
i used "loader" from react-router for this GET req,
fruits here is a list of fruits a user has,
different users have different "isLiked" properties

```
const response = useLoaderData()
const fruits = response.data;
```

fruits looks like this,

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'apple',
    isLiked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'orange',
    isLiked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'pineapple',
    isLiked: true
  },
];
```

this is my component,

```
const Fruits = () => {
  
  const [fruitIndex, setFruitIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentFruit, setCurrentFruit] = useState(fruits[fruitIndex]);
  const isThisFruitLiked = currentFruit.isLiked;

  const handlePreviousFruit = () => {
    if (fruitIndex === 0) {
      let lastFruitIndex = fruits.length - 1;
      setFruitIndex(lastFruitIndex);
      setCurrentFruit(fruits[lastFruitIndex]);
    } else {
      setFruitIndex((prev: any) => prev - 1);
      setCurrentFruit(fruits[fruitIndex - 1]);
    }
  };

  const handleNextFruit = () => {
    if (fruitIndex >= fruits.length - 1) {
      setFruitIndex(0);
      setCurrentFruit(fruits[0]);
    } else {
      setFruitIndex((prev: any) => prev + 1);
      setCurrentFruit(fruits[fruitIndex + 1]);
    }
  };

  const handleLike = async (id, isLiked) => {
    try {
      const reqBody = {
        id,
        isLiked,
      };

      if (isLiked) { // like a fruit
        const response = await axios.post(`/api/v1/fruits`, reqBody);
        const statusIsOk = response.status === 200;
        if (statusIsOk) {
          // change no to yes in "p tag"
        }
      } else { // un-like a fruit
        const response = await axios.delete(`/api/v1/fruits?id=${id}`);
        const statusIsOk = response.status === 200;
        if (statusIsOk) {
          // change yes to no in "p tag"
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>
          {' '}
          {`Do i like ${currentFruit.name}? ${
            currentFruit.isLiked ? 'yes' : 'no'
          }`}
        </p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            /* like or un-like a fruit */
            if (isThisFruitLiked) {
              handleLike(currentFruit.id, false);
            } else {
              handleLike(currentFruit.id, true);
            }
          }}
        >
          like button
        </button>
      </div>

      <br />
      <br />

      <button onClick={handlePreviousFruit}>previous</button>
      <button onClick={handleNextFruit}>next</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

i want my component to re-render everytime i like/un-like the fruit,
with my implementation, i need to restart the page for the component to update.

Comment: Where, or how, does the fetched `fruits` data from the loader and `useLoaderData` hook make its way to the UI? Can you [edit] to share your router and routing configuration, including loaders/actions, so we can see what is fetched and when/how?

Answer (score 0):

Well currently you are not setting the state in your handleLike function, and because of that your page is not rerendering.

Comment: Which state am i not setting?, should i set the currentFruit state? or do i need to hold fruits inside of a state and update that one instead?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to have your fruits as state.

```
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState();
const response = useLoaderData();

useEffect(()=>{
    const fruits = response.data;
},[response]);
```

Now you can update the liked field of fruits and call setFruits(...fruits).

However, you just want to force update keeping the current set up, you can use a dummy state to force an update.

```
const [_, forceUpdate] = useState({});

// when you need to force re-render
forceUpdate({});
```

This works because each object is different.